Pentax Zoom 70 macro AF FLASH PROBLEM
I have a Pentax Zoom-70 camera with new batteries and, according to the previous owner, in good working order. I haven't gotten around to putting film in the camera yet because I'd like to get to know the camera first, but I dont know how to use flash. Can't find any information on Google, so I came here.
Next to the lens there is a "flash" button, which should be activated so that you press the shutter button at the same time. the red light on the back of the camera, next to the viewfinder, lights up and starts flashing. when the flash is ready, it should stop flashing and just stay lit, but the concern is that it stays flashing. no matter how far I take a picture, it blinks. when I also try to press the shutter button, the flash does not fire. Maybe the flash isnt working because there is not film inside? i dont know…
English is my foreign language so im very sorry if its not very understandable, but i would be so thankful if anyone can help and know this camera better. camera is 1986 year

What kind of batteries are you using? Plain alkaline? Rechargeable ones?

i am using alkaline batteries

It's not clear from your question if you have access to the manual. Perhaps there's a setting that might answer your question. I found a copy online: https://ia801905.us.archive.org/13/items/central-manuals-camera_pentax_Zoom70-R.pdf/Zoom70-R_text.pdf

An electronic flash unit works by discharging a large, high voltage electrolytic capacitor across the flash tube.
From your description, while charging it never reaches sufficient voltage, which may be caused by a leak. Although the leak could come from a faulty isolation somewhere in the camera electronics (humidity), it also happens that these components do not age well and are usually the first to fail, and a Zoom70 is at least 20 years old.
So I wouldn't put too much hope in seeing this flash work again, unless you know someone handy with electronics who can replace the capacitor.
As a last ditch effort you could try to use high quality batteries (or switch to NiMH rechargeable ones), that could be able to deliver a bit more current (a lot more current for NiMH) to charge the capacitor and overcome any leak. The rechargeable option could be a good idea anyway because these cameras can cost more in disposable batteries than in film.
